# Sudden crash with black screen showing /dev/nvme0n1p2: but not able to open tty

Tags: drivers, nvidia

[image]

Before rebooting the system I just installed nvidia drivers manually from ubuntu Wayland. After starting the system it is showing this message in the screen with flickering. Now I am trying to go to tty1 with any commands from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.it is not going to terminal window. Any help would be really useful.

Comment: We don't know what OS & release you're using, so please tell us. Being specific as to how (what command etc) you installed nvidia drivers may also help (you mention from ubuntu Wayland, which makes no sense to me; Wayland is a [display server protocol](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland) and replacement for Xorg, but doesn't provide *drivers*)

Comment: Using ubuntu 18.04 bionic, tried installing with "sudo apt install nvidia-340"